# Issue with toolbar when keyboard appears

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have an xml layout with the next containers:

```
<ConstraintLayout>

<AppBarLayout></AppBarLayout>
<NestedScrollView></NestedScrollView>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

When a soft keyboard appears, I need to move up only my NestedScrollView container, because user need to see the full content on this page, BUT the AppBarLayout shouldn't move up. Is it possible, to move up ONLY NestedScrollView container?

Also, I have this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my Manifest and it shouldn't be changed

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="true" used this attribute in xml activity toolbar side. And manifest side android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" used this.